# Datatable is not working after ajax call in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

DataTable is not working properly. Data is shown on the table but search, pagination is not working. I use ajax request to get data.

Here my controller code

```
 $products = FoodItemPrice::with('items')->get();

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($products);
        }
```

Here is my ajax call

```
function getData(){

 
 $.ajax({

        url: "{{url('admin/category/')}}",
        method:"GET",
        contentType:false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType:"json",

        success: function(response){
              var data = ""
              var i = 1;
              $.each(response, function(key, value){
                data = data + "<tr>"
                data = data + "<td>"+i+++"</td>"
                data = data + "<td>"+value.name+"</td>"
                data = data + "<td class='actionBtn'>"
                data = data + "<button type='button' class='ms-btn-icon btn-dark mr-3' onclick='editCategory("+value.id+")'> <i class='flaticon-pencil'></i></button>"
                data = data + "<button type='button'class='ms-btn-icon btn-danger'  onclick='deleteData("+value.id+")'> <i class='flaticon-trash'></i></button>"
                data = data + "</td>"
                data = data + "</tr>"
              });
               $('tbody').html(data);
        
          }
  });
}  
getData();

Here is dataTable scripts 


    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable();
    } );
```

Where is the problem? Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Use Datatable's built in AJAX features instead of manually appending your own. This way it will take care of searching/pagination/ordering for you instead of you having to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Laravel Yajra Datatable and use built in Datatable server side data load
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables